# US passenger declaration currency requirement

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, money

My mother came from Korea to visit me in the US, and I am travelling back to Korea with her.

Do I need to make a joint passenger declaration when we leave together? She already had her money with her when she came to visit us.

If we make a joint declaration how they know we are family?

Comment: Whenever you fly into the USA you have to declare what you bring in, no matter whether you brought it out before. If asked about it, tell the officer that she brought it out. (But for safety reasons, you should not travel with the amounts of cash that trigger the questions.)

Comment: I mean report together customer declaration , while she go back with same airline.

Comment: If the total value of all currency you are carrying is less than USD 10,000 then it is not necessary to declare it to US authorities.  If it is USD 10,000 or greater, you must declare it.  It does not matter whether she brought the cash in with her earlier; the law requires it to be declared.

Answer (score 1):

Legally you need to declare any and all currency or negotiable monetary instruments when arriving in OR DEPARTING FROM the US IF their total value is over US$10,000. This amount is the combined value for all passengers travelling together, NOT per person.

Thus if between you and your mother you are carrying more than US$10,000 in cash/etc (regardless of the form or currency) then you will need to declare it.  Normally when departing the US there is no departure form that needs to be completed, however this does not negate the need to declare the currency to the CBP officers at the airport.  (Specifically you will need to complete form [FinCEN 105](https://www.fincen.gov/sites/default/files/shared/fin105_cmir.pdf).)

If you do not declare the currency, and you are caught, then you may need to forfeit the entire amount, so the risks of not declaring the currency are high.

Note that in general there are no rules against actually carrying more than $10,000 cash - the reporting requirements exist to help track money laundering and illegal actives.  As long as you have a valid reason for having/carrying the cash, and you correctly declare it, then there will be no issues, and no fees/taxes/etc to be paid on it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a joint declaration when you land in Korea, for currency you are carrying with you into Korea.

On departure from the US, there are no formal requirements - however, they do random checks with currency sniffing dogs.

Nothing to be alarmed about - you just have to show the source of the funds you carry.  A simple bank receipt showing the amount would suffice.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. If the amount is over $10k then there is a legal requirement to declare it.  Not declaring it and getting caught can lead to the confiscation of the entire amount!